# Using Selenium to Scrape Java-Heavy Website - Returning None

Tags: python, java, selenium, web-scraping

New coder here. I've been trying to **scrape** just one piece of text on a very java based website for a while now using Selenium. Not sure what I am doing wrong that this point.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://explorer.helium.com/accounts/13pm9juR7WPjAf7EVWgq5EQAaRTppu2EE7ReuEL9jpkHQMJCjn9")

earnings = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('text-base text-gray-600 mb-1 tracking-tight w-full break-all')

print(earnings)

driver.quit()
```

Image of attempted element to scrape :

[image]

I am trying to scrape that dollar amount in this container so I can eventually use it in a daily report that I am building.

Everything I have tried has resulted in it returning none. Even when I try to grab the text from that element.

Here is website link: https://explorer.helium.com/accounts/13pm9juR7WPjAf7EVWgq5EQAaRTppu2EE7ReuEL9jpkHQMJCjn9

Comment: can you try capturing any other data i.e. the title of the page?

Answer (score 0):

**You should wait until javascript loads, page loads, elements loads.**

```
_ = driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait;
```

**You can create condition until element appers.**

```
 ExpectedConditions ......  define selenium conditions

 //This is how we specify the condition to wait on.
 wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
```

**You can use XPATH !   The DOLLAR XPATH IS**

```
 /html/body/div[1]/div/article/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]
```

**FIREFOX XPATH FINDER**

```
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/xpath_finder/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this xpath

```
//*[@id="app"]/article/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]
```